# Ways to limit database calls? Specifically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

So I have two repositories: **Repository A** which gets info from **Database A** and **Repository B** which takes info from **Database B**.

In **Repository A**, I get a list of, let's say 5000, results. Now I want to obtain information from each one of those results with **Repository B** on a certain value from **Repository A** if that value is not empty or null.

Right now I have a foreach loop in **Repos A** and call **Repos B**'s method on each one. I know there has to be a less expensive way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you thought to put your data in the same database?

Comment: @JoePhilllips Unfortunately, I do not have access to do so. Also, the data is very different, so having all of that data in the same db would be a bit confusing.

Comment: Have you thought about building a dynamic LINQ where statement ?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to tell you how to do this.  Are you using Entity Framework?  Then you'd need to do some sort of bulk insert/update extension library.

Comment: You could use a Linked Server in SQL and do joins between databases.

Comment: The Linked Server option would be your best bet. Doing a foreach is very inefficient.

Comment: Just my two cents - linked servers do come with performance issues and weird authentication issues. Also, if you're keeping stored procs which talk to other servers, you're likely hard-coding the other server name, which makes it difficult to keep these things in source control and consistent across various test/dev/prod environments. Personally I avoid them unless absolutely necessary. For example, if you're ok with slightly stale data, a scheduled SSIS package moving data from A and B into a third "C" database might make life a little easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Entity Framework, you are allowed to use `WHERE X IN (...)` by doing a `Contains` in LINQ. So you'd do your stuff to retrieve all 5000 records from Repository A, put together a list of IDs, then build a single LINQ query for Repository B - this might suit your needs:

```
int[] fooIDs;
using (var contextA = new ContextA()) {
    fooIDs = contextA.Foos.Select(f => f.Id).ToArray();
}

using (var contextB = new ContextB()) {
    var people = contextB.People
        .Where(p => fooIDs.Contains(p.FooID));
}
```